# How to initialize let in javascript starting from 1

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript example which contains a for loop with let. Here I need to initialize the `i` value with 1 like 1,2,3 etc.. Now it's coming like 01,11,21,31 etc.. Here I should not change anything inside for loop.

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (let i in cars) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
  console.log(i + 1);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `var i = 1;`. Also that's an off-by-one error, arrays start at 0.

Comment: `let i in cars` -- this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Also, that's a misleading redeclaration.

Comment: `cars.forEach` is often a nicer way to go.

Comment: Your maybe after -> `for (let i of cars.slice(1)) {}`

Comment: @Keith I find it more likely given the issues with the code that initializing the starting index to 1 is an off-by-one error.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, looking again at his code, he just wants a standard for loop..  `for (let i = 1; i < cars.length; i ++) {}` or like mentioned a forEach with the index specifier, and of course the slice.

Answer (score 1):

The `for..in` loop will iterate through your array, this means that your variable `i` will take the value of each of your strings one by one

To achieve your goal, there is a simpler way, with a  single line of code :

```js
const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];

const text = cars.map(car => car + "<br>").join('');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

The `map` function will change each element in your array with another one, resulting in the following : `["BMW<br>", "Volvo<br>", "Saab<br>", "Ford<br>", "Fiat<br>", "Audi<br>"]`

Then, `join` will take all the strings in your array, and put them together

Answer (score 0):

A `forEach` loop would be a better and cleaner route for doing this. Run the code snippet below or check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2y6eqhb0/74/) to see how you can use `forEach` to loop through your cars array:

```js
    var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    text = "";
    
    cars.forEach(function(car){
      return text += car + '<br/>';
    });
      
    x.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
    <h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

---

If you are open to using the new JavaScript *ES6 syntax*, you can further shorten the above like this:

```
const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
const x = document.getElementById("demo");
text = "";

cars.forEach(car => text += `${car}<br/>`);

x.innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal `for loop`. And you can also delete the first declaration of `i`, because you already have `let i`.

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
  for (let i = 1; i < cars.length; i ++){
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
  console.log(i + 1);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Adding additional details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand why you need to offset because array start at zero.

but you get the result 01,21, 32, because you print  0+1=01, 1+1=11 you do not increment.

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
  for (let i in cars) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
i++;
console.log(i);
}
```

You can do acheive same result like this:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
cars.forEach (function(item){
text += item + "<br>";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many amazing answers, I will still like to share/add my answer

Using `“for…in” with array iteration` is a bad idea? Why? Read here for [detailed answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Coming back to the reason for unexpected behaviour.

For-in is meant to be primarily used with objects as a **key**

Now, Since you are taking an array,

```
for (let i in cars) {
console.log(i) 
}
```

Will log string **"1", "2", "3"** instead of integer **1, 2, 3.** Why? [Read here about the crazy nature of javascript](https://dev.to/promhize/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascripts-implicit-coercion-e23)

Hence, Best way is to use would be (copied from above answers)

```js
 

 //Method1
const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
const text = cars.map(car => car + "<br>").join('');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

 

 //Method 2
const cars1 = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
let text1 = "";
  for (let i = 1; i < cars1.length; i ++){
  text1 += cars1[i] + "<br>";
  console.log(i + 1);
}
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = text1;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    
 <h2>JavaScript Loops 1</h2>
 <div id="demo1"></div>
```